# Package inputenc Error: Unicode character (U+2005)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX

Tags: bibtex, citing, compiling, unicode, texlive-2020

I got an error message when I insert a citation in my document, it says ***Package inputenc Error: Unicode character (U+2005)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. ...Paul, J.~C. Conesa, S.~Shleev, A.~L. De***, in the .bbl file. Just like the screenshot.

[image: The error screenshot reported in TeXStudio]

Upon click the error message, I can get the following code and the issue is reported in Line 31.

```
\providecommand*{\mcitethebibliography}{\thebibliography}
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{endmcitethebibliography}
{\let\endmcitethebibliography\endthebibliography}{}
\begin{mcitethebibliography}{2}
\providecommand*{\natexlab}[1]{#1}
\providecommand*{\mciteSetBstSublistMode}[1]{}
\providecommand*{\mciteSetBstMaxWidthForm}[2]{}
\providecommand*{\mciteBstWouldAddEndPuncttrue}
  {\def\EndOfBibitem{\unskip.}}
\providecommand*{\mciteBstWouldAddEndPunctfalse}
  {\let\EndOfBibitem\relax}
\providecommand*{\mciteSetBstMidEndSepPunct}[3]{}
\providecommand*{\mciteSetBstSublistLabelBeginEnd}[3]{}
\providecommand*{\EndOfBibitem}{}
\mciteSetBstSublistMode{f}
\mciteSetBstMaxWidthForm{subitem}
{(\emph{\alph{mcitesubitemcount}})}
\mciteSetBstSublistLabelBeginEnd{\mcitemaxwidthsubitemform\space}
{\relax}{\relax}

\bibitem[Honda \emph{et~al.}(2017)Honda, Watanabe, Hagiwara, Ida, and
  Ishihara]{HONDA2017400}
Y.~Honda, M.~Watanabe, H.~Hagiwara, S.~Ida and T.~Ishihara, \emph{Applied
  Catalysis B: Environmental}, 2017, \textbf{210}, 400 -- 406\relax
\mciteBstWouldAddEndPuncttrue
\mciteSetBstMidEndSepPunct{\mcitedefaultmidpunct}
{\mcitedefaultendpunct}{\mcitedefaultseppunct}\relax
\EndOfBibitem
\bibitem[Jarne \emph{et~al.}(2019)Jarne, Paul, Conesa, Shleev, De Lacey, and
  Pita]{doi:10.1002/celc.201900360}
C.~Jarne, L.~Paul, J.~C. Conesa, S.~Shleev, A.~L. De Lacey and M.~Pita,
  \emph{ChemElectroChem}, 2019, \textbf{6}, 2755--2761\relax
\mciteBstWouldAddEndPuncttrue
\mciteSetBstMidEndSepPunct{\mcitedefaultmidpunct}
{\mcitedefaultendpunct}{\mcitedefaultseppunct}\relax
\EndOfBibitem
\end{mcitethebibliography}
```

And the BibTeX code for the citation is provided as below:

```
@article{doi:10.1002/celc.201900360,
author = {Jarne, Carmen and Paul, Logan and Conesa, Jose Carlos and Shleev, Sergey and De Lacey, Antonio L. and Pita, Marcos},
title = {Underpotential Photoelectrooxidation of Water by SnS2−Laccase Co-catalysts on Nanostructured Electrodes with Only Visible-Light Irradiation},
journal = {ChemElectroChem},
volume = {6},
number = {10},
pages = {2755-2761},
doi = {10.1002/celc.201900360},
url = {https://chemistry-europe.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/celc.201900360},
eprint = {https://chemistry-europe.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/celc.201900360},
year = {2019}
}
```

And my preamble is written as below:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times,mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[numbers, super, sort & compress, comma]{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks, citecolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[font=normal, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D\do\E\do\F\do\G\do\H\do\I\do\J
    \do\K\do\L\do\M\do\N\do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T\do\U\do\V
    \do\W\do\X\do\Y\do\Z\do\[\do\\\do\]\do\^\do\_\do\`\do\a\do\b
    \do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j\do\k\do\l\do\m\do\n
    \do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t\do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z
    \do\.\do\@\do\\\do\/\do\!\do\_\do\|\do\;\do\>\do\]\do\)\do\,
    \do\?\do\'\do+\do\=\do\#}
```

I'm totally not familiar with this issue so I sincerely ask for assistance from the community.

Comment: @CampanIgnis look harder, it is there:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle confirmed by manual checking, but my browser is still unable to find that char. I retracted my vote and deleted my comment. Thank you very much.

Comment: Off-topic: (a) Don't load the `url` package and then define a complicated `\UrlBreaks` macro. Instead, just load the `xurl` package. (b) Whatever else you do, load the `hyperref` package *last*.

Answer (score 4):

U+2005 is a 1/4 em space character. It would be best to delete them and replace by normal spaces but you could do

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2005}{\hspace{0.25em}}
```

But don't do that, the character is between De Lacy:

```
  U+0020 SPACE     \space
  U+0044 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D     D
  U+0065 LATIN SMALL LETTER E     e
  U+2005 FOUR-PER-EM SPACE     &emsp14; \hspace{0.25em}<<<<<<<<<<<<
  U+004c LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L     L
  U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A     a
  U+0063 LATIN SMALL LETTER C     c
  U+0065 LATIN SMALL LETTER E     e
  U+0079 LATIN SMALL LETTER Y     y
  U+002c COMMA     &comma; \mathcomma ,
  U+0020 SPACE     \space
```

Replace that by a normal space.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your comment reveals the real reason for this issue. I found it as well and I have replaced the space so it has been resolved. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is wondering how you actually find the character (it is invisible after all), you can paste what you understand to be the problematic portion of your code [here](https://regexr.com/) and use the [regex expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987362/how-to-get-vim-to-highlight-non-ascii-characters)

```
/[^\x00-\x7F]
```

to highlight non-ascii characters (try it with the OP's bibtex snippet). Better yet, since we are given a warning about which character isn't supported, you can do a [vim search](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3557/can-i-search-for-a-unicode-combining-character-in-vim),

```
/<ctr-v>u2005
```